# Build, clean issue with android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.2

i am using android studio 2.2 preview 5 i just switched to this version last week and since last week i have not been able to build my projects.
i get the following error

Error:Could not delete path 'C:\Users\Matthew\AndroidStudioProjects\Repository\LMS\passcode\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v12'.

i have tried various suggestions such as

- using terminal to run gradlew clean cmd
- invalidate caches/ restart
- Delete the intermidate folder and restart android studio
  and many other suggestions

[this is the picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5ymc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

i actually get it to solve it by changing my classpath to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

from the previous version

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2'
```

which supports instant run and the error of inability to delete some directories went away.
But before that i was stopping the

> JAVA se Platform

through the Task manager but i have to do that before running the app everytime. but changing the classpath actually solved the issue just that i can't make use of instant run which am ok with.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to close the R.java file I opened in a text editor before.
After closing the text editor the message disappeared.
(I'm on Android Studio 2.2.2)

Answer (score -1):

I also had this error. I am on Windows 10 and turning off real-time protection in Windows Defender solved it for me.